# export FLASK_CONFIG='development' on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

in my flask Application I run command `export FLASK_CONFIG='development'` 
locally to run application. But now in heroku when I run command `heroku run init`get the error that I know I should import export FLASK_CONFIG='development But how can I do in heroku

the error:

```
(venv)peg@peg:~/Fast-monks$ heroku run python manage.py shell
Running `python manage.py shell` attached to terminal... up, run.6078
postgres://fboastbcwkwdsa:bIrdHsid_Zv3GOzyrhCB9x1oig@ec2-174-129-1-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfg3hpuotv5lal
postgres://fboastbcwkwdsa:bIrdHsid_Zv3GOzyrhCB9x1oig@ec2-174-129-1-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dfg3hpuotv5lal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.environ['FLASK_CONFIG'] or 'default')
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'FLASK_CONFIG'
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.28.4 update available.
```

manage.py:

```
app = create_app(os.environ['FLASK_CONFIG'] or 'default')
magrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

config.py:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = 'Thisismysecretkey'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL',
             'postgresql+psycopg2://peg:1234@localhost/app')
    print SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI


class HerokuConfig(ProductionConfig):
    def init_app(cls, app):
        ProductionConfig.init_app(app)
        import logging
        from logging import StreamHandler
        file_handler = StreamHandler()
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)


config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    'testing': TestingConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
    'heroku': HerokuConfig,
    'default': DevelopmentConfig}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the environment variable via the `heroku` command:

```
heroku config:set FLASK_CONFIG=development
```

Although your manage.py looks wrong, you seem to be trying to set a default in case the var does not exist, but the keyerror is raised before it can get to the default. Use this instead:

```
app = create_app(os.environ.get('FLASK_CONFIG', 'default'))
```